# IIS Redirection 301 vs 302

Tags: redirect, iis-7

I want to send users who type `www.mysite.com` to `mysite.com`.

Achieving this is easy using IIS 7 Redirection. But what confuses me is the selection of status code sent back (`Permanent-301` or `Found-302`), especially to the search engines, so the ranking is not affected.

Appreciate your response. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http redirect: 301 vs. 302 (temporary vs. permanent)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-vs-302-temporary-vs-permanent), [What HTTP redirection method should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396632/what-http-redirection-method-should-i-use)

Comment: @CodyGray - That's for when we move from an old domain to new domain. But in this `www` situation, which would be better? Would be nice to know what StackOverflow uses..